# How to display product details in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

[image]

I have a `Products` page which display a list of products. When i click a Product's `Details` button, it should be display product details.

in this query, display all product details..

`DataRow drProductDetails = system.GetDataRow("Select ProductDetails from TBLPRODUCTS where ProductID=ProductID");`

[image]

Can someone please help me in the SQL query to display `Product Details`

Comment: Can you share your table structure?  Is the query you gave an example or does it actually work?

Comment: Change your select to select * ?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? Don't tag products not directly involved...

Comment: @sagi we generally should avoid using select *.

Comment: The query you posted will return the entire table. You need to modify your where predicate so it gets the row where ProductID = [TheCurrentlySelectedRowsProductID]. You also should parameterize this query.